# Как сделать доску для игры `connect4` с закругленными углами и вдавленными ячейками?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Я хочу сделать плату `connect4` с точными стилями и заданными свойствами.
Это выглядит так (не обращайте внимания на элементы, которыми он заполнен).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать боковые стороны платы изогнутыми с боков, как на картинке?
Пожалуйста, попробуйте использовать HTML-элементы только для решения этой проблемы. Если это будет какой-нибудь простой SVG, пожалуйста, добавьте его.

В настоящее время мой код выглядит так:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) { 
    document.getElementById("cont").appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cont {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 80px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 80px);
    background-color: #84A4FC;
    width: fit-content;
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#cont div {
    background-color: white;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 6px #00000040;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;

}
```

```html
<div id="cont"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to make a connect4 board with rounded corners and curved sides?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66391411/7394871) от участника  [@Maheer Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9819146/maheer-ali).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66391411/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете сделать  это приблизительно так, используя фильтр SVG (подробнее здесь: [https://dev.to/afif/css-shapes-with-ounded-corners-56h](https://dev.to/afif/css-shapes-with-rounded-corners-56h))

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
  document.getElementById("cont").appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 80px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 80px);
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  /* we need a background to cover only the middle part not the whole element*/
  background:linear-gradient(#84A4FC 0 0) center/calc(100% - 40px) calc(100% - 40px) no-repeat;
  filter:url(#round); /* this */
}

#cont div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0px 3px 6px #00000040,
    0 0 0 10px #84A4FC; /* added this */
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont"></div>

<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="round">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66392088/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Comment: а  фотки ? хотелось бы увидеть как вставить фотки в  цикле - в то место как на скрине

Comment: @MaximLensky Попробуй, только будет приветствоваться твой ответ.

Comment: я на оборот хотел это увидеть - получается что Temani Afif. не доделал -

Comment: @MaximLensky Всё он сделал, как надо. Прочти вопрос -  `Это выглядит так (не обращайте внимания на элементы, которыми он заполнен)`.

Comment: Реально круть! Пара фильтров, а как код сокращает. Спасибо.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: почистим комменты. Если что я в svg-чате ещё часок.

Comment: но плюс я всё равно поставил